# React JS get data using Axios

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, object, axios

I am facing an problem in React, How to get value from data using Axios.
how can i get end_date from json Data.

Data:

```
Array[{"id":"1","location_id":null,"staff_id":"1","staff_any":"0","service_id":"1","custom_service_name":null,"custom_service_price":null,"start_date":"2020-05-06 01:00:00","end_date":"2020-05-06 01:15:00" }]
```

My Code:

```
    this.state = {
          data: []
      }


  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`http://localhost/babershop_App/wordpress/wp-json/testplugin/v1/testroute`)
      .then(res => {
        const data = res.data;
        this.setState({ data });
      })
  }

render() {    
  return (
      <div>
        <ul>
         {this.state.data.map(data => <li>{data.end_date}</li>)}
        </ul>
      </div>
  )
}
```

But my code is not working they give an error

What should i do? Can anyone help me?

Comment: what is the error you get? Your array data seems corrupted, for example strings are not ended but I dont know if this is only a typo in the post or actual problem

Comment: TypeError: this.state.data.map is not a function [@Nikos M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3591273/nikos-m)

Comment: by the time `this.state.data.map()` runs, your `data` probably is empty, you should have a separate check on this case

Comment: How can i get data in render() function? [@Nikos M ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3591273/nikos-m)

Comment: what should i do? can you do some code plz? [@Duc Hong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2599144/duc-hong)

Comment: Print out after `const data = res.data;` to see what data is, use `console.log (data);`.

Comment: yes it a check on console.log(data) it gives an output [@wang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6021280/wang)

Comment: Array[{"id":"1","location_id":null,"staff_id":"1","staff_any":"0","service_id":"1","custom_service_name":null,"custom_service_price":null,"start_date":"2020-05-06 01:00:00","end_date":"2020-05-06 01:15:00"}] [@wang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6021280/wang)

Comment: Are you sure `res.data` is an array? If you comment out the `setState` line does it throw the error with the initial empty array? Have you logged `res.data`?

Comment: yes  i have also check console.log(res.data);  [Drew Reese](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8690857/drew-reese)

Comment: And if you don't update state it still throws error? If it renders fine until you fetch data and update state and it's now no longer an array, investigate that.

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of `console.log (data)` in the console and add it to the question?

Answer (score 0):

Your `render` function should check for the case when data is empty. Something like this:

```js
...

render() {
  const { data } = this.state;

  // Checking your data in your console
  console.log('>> Data: ', data);

  
  // Return a custom HTML block for empty data state
  if (!data || data.length === 0)
    return null;
    
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
       {this.state.data.map(data => <li key={data.id}>{data.end_date}</li>)}
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: array::map can handle an empty array, OP has issue where `this.state.data` becomes *something other than* an array.

Comment: yes, you're right, usually that happens due to a corrupted response, I'm still waiting on the OP for his error response

Comment: this code is not running [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2599144/duc-hong)

Comment: please open your console log and see what your `data` outputs, and paste here @MHasan

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the result returned by the backend is an error. Try `JSON.parse (data.replace ("Array", ""))`, convert the `data` to Array. Or remove `Array` in the backend.

```
this.setState({ data: JSON.parse (data.replace ("Array", ""))});
```

Comment: where should a edit this line? JSON.parse (data.replace ("Array", "")) [@wang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6021280/wang)

Comment: @MHasan Since the printed data contains a string "Array", the data is not a JSON type data. Remove "Array" to convert it to JSON type, and then use `JSON.parse` to convert it to an array.

Comment: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): data.replace is not a function [@wang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6021280/wang)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a map error than it is because the state.data is initially empty. Try this...

```
this.state.data?this.state.data.map(()=>{
//...do something
}) : ''
```

This is because the API takes time to return response